# PARSE ERROR: pandas-datareader fails to obtain data for oanda historical currency rates

Tags: web-scraping, pandas-datareader

```
from pandas_datareader.oanda import get_oanda_currency_historical_rates
start, end = "2016-01-01", "2016-06-01"
quote_currency = "USD"
base_currency = ["EUR", "GBP", "JPY"]
df_rates = get_oanda_currency_historical_rates(
start, end,
quote_currency=quote_currency,
base_currency=base_currency
)
print(df_rates)
```

ParserError: ',' expected after '"'. Error could possibly be due to parsing errors in the skipped footer rows (the skipfooter keyword is only applied after Python's csv library has parsed all rows).

Comment: This has been reported [as a bug](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues/343).